# Does "are not to be accepted" mean "won't be accepted"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA17-PR94&lpg=RA17-PR94&dq=wordsearch%2041%2011oo%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know&source=bl&ots=ErLXYGF_NJ&sig=A3lDaPvhhsRRssuOW8WhmYRsLC0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTquTWy-PNAhWCVRQKHaC6DksQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=wordsearch%2041%2011oo%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know&f=false)):

> One of the insidious forms of discrimination is that based upon age.
>   We have become aware through education and publicity that bias and discrimination based upon race, color, creed, and sex **are not to be accepted**

Does **"are not to be accepted"** mean **"won't be accepted"**? If so, what makes this structure different from **"wont be accepted"**? Why the author used that?

Comment: This pill is to be taken with food.

Comment: *BE to be* implies obligation rather than prediction: bias and discrimination are not permitted and **should** not be accepted. But the author is doubtless aware that all too often they **are** accepted.

Comment: @StoneyB with this regard, why the author didn't say should not be accepted? or must not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the choice of "are not to be" over a modal...

**should** would have cast it as an exhortation.

**must** would have cast it as an imperative or rule that we are obliged to follow.

**are not to be** is very close to **must not be** but it casts the obligation as an *instruction* of some kind. We have been **instructed** (unenlightened souls that we are) not to discriminate on the basis of sex, race, color, and creed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in order of their appearance:

> Does ***"are not to be accepted"*** mean ***"won't be accepted"***?

In short, the answer is no, they don't mean the same thing. As StoneyB mentions in their comment, the former is a statement that an obligation exists to perform an action, while the latter states a prediction of an action occurring.

> What makes ***"won't be accepted"*** different?

Essentially, the difference is between obligation (are not to be) and prediction (won't be). To combine them in an understandable sentence, take the following:

*Broken or ripped dollar bills **are not to be** accepted as payment, but that doesn't mean I **won't** find some in the till at the end of the night.*

That sentences states that there is an obligation not to accept ripped dollar bills, but predicts -- in negative language -- that some ripped dollar bills will be accepted in defiance of this obligation.

> Why did the author use [***are not to be*** as opposed to ***won't be***]?

Because the author wanted to convey the obligation. As the author states elsewhere, publicity has shown such discrimination **does** exist and **is** practiced (so predicting it not to occur would be either wrong or a lie); the author is trying to make the point that it **shouldn't** happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  why the author didn't say **should not be accepted**? or **must not**? I mean he did not use a modal.